# SQL Using Count() to find ids with frequencies other than MAX

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called book_author with schema (book_id: int, author: string).

I am trying to obtain the books with the second highest number of authors.

That said, if the table was something like this:

```
book_id   |   author
_____________________
1         |   John
2         |   Anna
3         |   Dan
1         |   Robert
2         |   Kim
1         |   Oscar
3         |   Bill
```

The return would be something like this. Book_id = 1 is not in the table because it has the max.

```
book_id    | NUM_AUTHORS
2          |  2
3          |  2
```

My initial attempt was as follows, but this simply returns the book ids with the Maximum number of authors, not second to largest... Any way I could modify this?

```
SELECT book_id, COUNT(*) AS NUM_AUTHORS FROM book_author GROUP BY book_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(SELECT MAX(c) FROM
(SELECT COUNT(book_id) AS c
FROM book_author
GROUP BY book_id));
```

Comment: Do you want just the ones that are second highest? What about third or 4th highest?

Comment: @clinomaniac only second!

Comment: What if there are ties?

Comment: @GordonLinoff if multiple rows come in second place all should be displayed

Comment: @user7090180 - And if there is a tie for 1st?  The book with the second highest count will have the same count as the book with the highest count...

Comment: @MatBailie For example, if two books have 5 authors, and 5 authors is the maximum number, but three books have 4 authors, it should print those three book ids and how many authors they have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with ordering the counts in descending order and getting the 2nd row (with offset and limit)

```
select book_id,count(*)
from book_author
group by book_id
having count(*) = (select distinct cnt
                   from (select count(*) as cnt
                         from book_author 
                         group by book_id 
                        ) t
                   order by cnt desc 
                   limit 1 offset 1
                  )
```

Comment: What if two authors have same max count?

Comment: To be picky, you should aggregate the sub query again, or apply a distinct before applying the limit/offset.   If two authors are tied for the highest number of books, then this will return books by the author with the most books.  So, it shouldn't find the number of books by the second most prevalent author, but the second highest frequency score.  *(4, 4, 3, 3 => 3)*

Comment: @MatBailie .. edited the answer to handle ties based on your suggestion.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala quick question - what is the isolated 't' character  in the code you provided?

Comment: @user7090180 .. it is an alias for the derived table (which counts rows per book_id)..it can be anything.

Comment: (Well, *almost* anything)